# Checking whether Selenium WebDriver points to a window or not

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Consider the below code:

```
getCurrentUrl(driver);
driver.close();
getCurrentUrl(driver);

public void getCurrentUrl (WebDriver driver) {
    if (driver window is not closed)
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    else
        System.out.println("Window is not available");
}
```

Please let me know how to perform the "driver window is not closed" check in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm ... Consider this just as a guess. But I feel like that when you call `driver` variable after you close it, you can get `NullPointerException` because it will be `null`

But anyway. I would implement it like this:

```
public void getCurrentUrl (WebDriver driver) {
try {
   System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
} catch (Exception e) { // the most top one
   System.out.println("Window is not available");
  }
}
```

There is possibly better and cleaner way of doing it. But I am not Java programmer and my gut feeling tells me this will work

Comment: You are right. Definitely we will get the `NullPointerException` when there is no driver instance. But my question is Is it possible to check the`alive` status of a Web Driver instance like `Thread.alive`?

Comment: @Manigandan there's no better way to do that, but you can create an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues) to ask for a new feature instead of using the dirty `getCurrentUrl()`